# How to check if a process has been stopped or started within a time frame?

Tags: powershell

I would like to run a Powershell script that would tell me if a process with a specific name has been stopped/started within a given time frame (e.g. 24 hours). I basically want what this does: https://serverfault.com/questions/416536/last-restart-start-time-of-a-windows-service however I would like it for processes (.exe).

Can the below be butchered to accomodate a process that doesn't exist as a service?

```
(Get-EventLog -LogName "System" -Source "Service Control Manager" -EntryType "Information" -Message "*Computer Browser service*running*" -Newest 1).TimeGenerated;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post describes your exact question.
https://superuser.com/questions/1052541/how-can-i-get-a-history-of-running-processes

I'll add the most important part in a quote for archive purposes.

> Press Win+R and type gpedit.msc to open the group policy manager In
> the left pane, navigate to
>
> Local Computer Policy \ Computer Configuration \ Windows Settings 
> Security Settings \ Local Policies \ Audit Policy
>
> In the right pane, double-click "Audit process tracking" and check
> both boxes
>
> From now on, all process creations and deletions (and failed attempts
> at same) will appear in the Security log.